# Unity drag and throw a gameobject (ex: sprite) with mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, gameobject

I want to throw a gameObject (like a sprite) with my mouse.
I would like to handle to power if the mouvement is fast.

I've try to develop it myself but I haven't found yet.

In my mind I think I need to do this :

- on mouse down : get the position
- 0.5secs after of on mouse up : get the new position
  and calculate the distance between the 2 points.
  Conclude a direction and a force.

What do you think about this ?

Comment: Unity has a standard asset for dragging Rigidbodies, and I also found this http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=DragObject . You can look at it for inspiration. However, the waiting for 0.5 seconds part is tricky, and it sounds like it needs a coroutine (see http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html ) .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It will be in 2D, is it possible ?

Comment: Please use the correct tags http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created something fairly similar to this. You should do [OnMouseDown()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) then [Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) on the position of the mouse click. Then your Raycast should grab the collider of the GameObject that was hit. Then you send a message, [SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html), to that collider telling it what you want to do.

All the links I have given you and some trial an error will help you construct what you need, that is how I created my level editor which is in essence the same thing. Note that all links have code samples that teach you all you need to do. Just use your imagination and you can get it done!

Just start coding. If you get stuck then ask a more specific question and someone will help you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Your solution is good and I've read each link. What is the difference between calling directly the method and SendMessage ?

Comment: But I want to send the object from the sprite to the direction and not clicking directly in the point of destination. 

Thanks a lot for helping me in my beginning in Unity :)

Comment: @user3692403 No problem. The difference between calling directly and SendMessage is that calling directly is faster if you have the reference to the class object, but if you don't then SendMessage will do the job well. Also if my answer has solved your problem then you can accept to let others know it has been solved.